# "tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider" error on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm receiving the following error when running react native app using expo on IPhone (on android it's working correctly)

[An image of the error is attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l02c6.jpg)

In addition, this is my package.json file:

> {
> "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
> "scripts": {
> "start": "expo start",
> "android": "expo start --android",
> "ios": "expo start --ios",
> "web": "expo start --web",
> "eject": "expo eject"
> },

> "dependencies": {
> "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.4",
> "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
> "axios": "^0.21.1",
> "expo": "~40.0.0",
> "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
> "expo-font": "^9.0.0",
> "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
> "react": "16.13.1",
> "react-dom": "16.13.1",
> "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
> "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
> "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.1",
> "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
> "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
> "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
> "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
> "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^7.0.0",
> "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
> "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
> "redux": "^4.0.5"
> },

> "devDependencies": {
> "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"   },
> "private": true
> }

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have two versions of `react-native-safe-area-context` installed in your app. remove `react-native-safe-area-context` from your dependencies and run `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

Comment: Other solutions suggested to reinstall react-native-gesture-handler, tried that but didn't work for me. This, however, worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110#issuecomment-668625988) you can find the solution approved by a collaborator.

In my case, problem persisted and I did as suggested in the link above but I skip steps 2 and 5. I kept expo version in 4.1.0.

1. delete node_modules and your lockfile (package-lock.json /
   yarn.lock)
2. change the expo package version in package.json to 38.0.8
3. remove react-native-safe-area-context from your package.json
4. run yarn or npm install
5. run expo install react-native-safe-area-context

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
cd ios && pod install
```