# React Native: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCMaskedView

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, package.json

i'm trying to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-masked-view/masked-view, I'm using npm, when I do the import and try to run my app, returns me an error:
Tried to register two views with the same name RNCMaskedView.

I already tried the solutions of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991289/tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-rncsafeareaprovider-error-on-io), but doesn't help.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --port 19003",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1262.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.10",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### tl;dr.

From the Expo documentation on [MaskedView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/masked-view/):

> You can only have one of either `@react-native-community/masked-view` or `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` installed in your project at any given time. React Navigation v5.x requires `@react-native-community/masked-view`, so you should use that package instead if you are using React Navigation v5.x.

`react-native-skeleton-placeholder@5.0.0` depends on `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` which conflicts with `@react-native-community/masked-view`. To resolve this, either remove any dependency to `@react-native-community/masked-view` or, as in my case, [patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) `react-native-skeleton-placeholder` to use `@react-native-community/masked-view` instead.

#### Why?

`react-native-skeleton-placeholder@5.0.0` depends on `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view`. However, in my case `@react-navigation/stack` has a dependency to `@react-native-community/masked-view`, causing a conflict and runtime/build errors.

There are several bug reports on this topic. One of the more helpful ones is this: https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/111

One of the authors stated [this](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/111#issuecomment-826790877) in the comments:

> I'm not planning to maintain `@react-native-community/masked-view` package, as the namespace has changed to `@react-native-masked-view`

Hence, the best way forward seems to remove the dependency to `@react-native-community/masked-view` and use `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` instead. Unfortunately, in my case wasn't possible. Instead, I ended up [patching](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) `react-native-skeleton-placeholder` to use `@react-native-community/masked-view`

This is my patch file:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder/lib/SkeletonPlaceholder.js b/node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder/lib/SkeletonPlaceholder.js
index 3c35038..41f7a8f 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder/lib/SkeletonPlaceholder.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder/lib/SkeletonPlaceholder.js
@@ -35,7 +35,7 @@ var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
 const React = __importStar(require("react"));
 const react_native_1 = require("react-native");
-const masked_view_1 = __importDefault(require("@react-native-masked-view/masked-view"));
+const masked_view_1 = __importDefault(require("@react-native-community/masked-view"));
 const react_native_linear_gradient_1 = __importDefault(require("react-native-linear-gradient"));
 const SCREEN_WIDTH = react_native_1.Dimensions.get("window").width;
 function SkeletonPlaceholder({ children, backgroundColor = "#E1E9EE", speed = 800, highlightColor = "#F2F8FC", direction = "right", }) {
```

You can apply this to your local installation with the [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) module.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yarn resolutions try to set the masked-view dependency to the same version you are using in your yarn.lock.

Example you have `"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10"` Add this to the resolutions section and it should resolve any sub-dependency with that version.

Try this command to quickly see if you have version mismatches.

```sh
yarn list --pattern @react-native-community/masked-view
```

That should output the dependency tree of your `yarn.lock` file.

After you fix these dependency mismatches you will need to perform a clean install IE remove all node_modules, reset cache, clean xcode build, pod install etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm using npm, and I don't see any disparity in the versions.

Answer (score 1):

**The fastest solution is the below:**

**First need to change the package in the below path:**
(Access the below react-native-skeleton-placeholder file)

node_modules/react-native-skeleton-placeholder/lib/SkeletonPlaceholder.js

*Search the below line and change it accordingly...*

***From:***

```
const masked_view_1 = __importDefault(require("@react-native-masked-view/masked-view"));
```

***To:***

```
const masked_view_1 = __importDefault(require("@react-native-community/masked-view"));
```

***Then to keep the below in the package.json***

```
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
```

Thanks & Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a `react-native-safe-area-context` version in my `package.json`  different from the one used by one of my dependencies.

I wrote my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74447304/1128216)